# Showing Fragment title in custom Actionbar

Tags: android, android-fragments

i want to use custom actionbar with fragment title.but this method only display application name for all fragments.i need to use appropriate fragment name in actionbar.

```
 getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

         LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
         View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.title, null);
         //if you need to customize anything else about the text, do it here.
         //I'm using a custom TextView with a custom font in my layout xml so all I need to do is set title

         ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(getActivity().getTitle());

         //assign the view to the actionbar
         getActivity().getActionBar().setCustomView(v);
```

Comment: set the desired text in custom view's textView like : `((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("name_you_want");`

Comment: You need to set the desired name for each and every activity at the time of calling an activity in your actionbar.

Comment: @SweetWisher can you tell me how to use this for an activity?

Comment: Did you check the answer I posted?

Comment: i used another method dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define a method which will update the title of action bar and call that method from ever activity / Fragment's `onResume()`

In activity :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

    // For activity
    setActionbarTitle("title"); 

    // For Fragment
    ((ParentActivtyNAme)getActivty).setActionbarTitle("title");
}
```

setActionbarTitle Method :

```
public void setActionbarTitle(String title) {
    textTitle.setText(title);
}
```

And initialize `textTitle` when you set Custom View in Actionbar :

```
 textTitle= ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title));
```

Hope it helps you ツ